# How to sort at server side without a query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

My app is written in expressjs, handlebars, mongoose/mongodb and I can't get my heard around how do I sort my array before handlebars prints it.

***app.js (entry point)***

```
var debug = require('debug');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars')

... 
...

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('hbs', exphbs({ extname: '.hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout' }));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'gh jewellery',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: false }


}));


app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('middleware was called');
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    req.session.LoggedIn = false;

    next();
});
```

Above I am declaring the session to be local variable as I will be using it in my layout view. Which in brief consists of the navbar that will hold notification icon, username icon, and message icon with it's respective data. Below is the layout.hbs

***layout.hbs***

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   ...

    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" id="cus" href="/" style="font-size:12px;"></a>

        {{#if session.loggedIn}}

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="far fa-bell fa-lg" style="color:darkblue;"></i><span class="label label-info"> {{session.user.notification.counter}}</span>
                    </a>


                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        {{#each session.user.notification.notidata}}
                        <div class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            <div>
                                <h6>{{data.heading}}</h6>
                                <small>{{data.para}}</small>

                                <small class="text-muted">{{notidate}}</small>
                                <a style="float:right; font-size:8px;" href="#" class="badge badge-secondary">Mark As Read</a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        {{/each}}
                        <form action="/logout" method="post">
                            <button class="btn btn-light btn-block logoutbutton" type="submit">View All Notifications</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="far fa-envelope fa-lg" style="color:darkblue;"></i><span class="label label-info"> {{session.user.message.counter}}</span>
                    </a>


                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                            <div>
                                <h6>Heading</h6>
                                <small>This is the paragramgh look pretty cool to me if you ask!</small>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <form action="/logout" method="post">
                            <button class="btn btn-light btn-block logoutbutton" type="submit">View All Messages</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ">
                    <a class="nav-link " href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg" style="color:darkblue;"> {{session.user.username}}</i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/profile/{{session.user._id}}">Profile</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/adreqform">Post an Order</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/managereq">Manage Order Requests</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                        <form action="/logout" method="post">
                            <button class="btn btn-light btn-block logoutbutton" type="submit">Logout</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>

            {{/if}}
            {{#unless session.loggedIn}}
            <div class="navbar-text ml-auto">
                Hello! <a href="/signup" style="color:darkblue">Sign up</a> or <a href="/login" style="color:darkblue">Login</a>
            </div>

            {{/unless}}
        </div>

    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7">
                {{{body}}}
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="w-100 ">
                    <br />

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                            <hr>
                            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="w-100">
                    <br />

                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
                            <hr>
                            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



    <!--<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown();
        });
    </script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

***user.models.js (mongoose model)***

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema = new Schema({

    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    company: String,
    contact: Number,
    country: String,
    isLoggedIn: Boolean,
    createdOn: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    ads: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ad' }],
    notification: {
        counter: Number,
        notidata: [{
            notiId: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            notidate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            data: {
                heading: String,
                para: String
            },
            notistatus: {type: Boolean, default: false}
        }]
    }

});


var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

***myroute.js (partial code that is enough to explain the issue I have)***

```
                var user3 = {
                username: req.body.username,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password,
                country: req.body.country


            };

            var newuser = new User(user3);
            newuser.save(function (err, newuser) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);

                }
                req.session.user = newuser;
                req.session.loggedIn = true;
                req.session.save();
```

Notice above how I assign the `req.session.user` to the current user through

```
req.session.user = newuser;
```

Now the issue I have is, since ***layout.hbs*** isn't hitting a route while it is being called the first time I open `localhost:3000` at what point can I sort the `notidata` array. Basically, all `user` documents contain notification data in `notidata` array and is being printed in ***layout.hbs*** with the help of `#each` helper. **I want the `notidata` to sort by the date and then get printed** but since there is no route that is being hit, I don't know where can I do something like `User.find().sort(notidate: 'desc')...` or maybe that is not even how it will be done? It is session.user that is printing the `notidata` I am so lost.

Since `session.user` is what is printing `notidata` in ***layout.hbs*** how do I sort it before it gets to view? I read somewhere I can use custom handlebars helper on the front-end which first sorts then iterates the `notidata` but I want to sort it back-end then bring it to the view.

Comment: I think user date will return back when he/she logged in. do you have any route which indicates authentication or `/login`? there is you can find the user and return it in custom way

Comment: **Has been solved here** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198702/how-to-sort-sub-document-array-in-mongoose-mongodb/53198984#53198984

Answer (score 0):

when you created the new user and save it, it will return your user object. so you can get it and manipulate or change it in any order you want:

```
   newuser.save(function (err, newuser) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);

            }
            //here before returning the whole user object you can sort it:
            const notidata = newUser.notification.notidata;
            const sortedNotiData = notidata.sort(function(a,b){
            return new Date(a.notidate) - new Date(b.notidate);   
          })
           // now sortedNotiDate contain sorted data so:
            newuser.nottification.notidata = sortedNotiData;
            req.session.user = newuser;
            req.session.loggedIn = true;
            req.session.save();
```