# How to sort sub-document array in mongoose/mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

***user (mongodb document)***

```
{
  "_id": "5bccfb7515bc6d0c6872ed91",
  "notification": {
    "notidata": [
      {
        "data": {
          "para": "Your Ad '1' has been successfully submitted."
        },
        "notistatus": false,
        "_id": "5be35d89113aec40c4ca7517",
        "notidate": "2018-11-07T21:47:53.803Z"
      },
      {
        "data": {
          "para": "Your Ad '2' has been successfully submitted."
        },
        "notistatus": false,
        "_id": "5be35d92113aec40c4ca7519",
        "notidate": "2018-11-07T21:48:02.729Z"
      }
    ],
    "counter": 4
  },
  "ads": [],
  "username": "mesam",
  "email": "mesam@hotmal.com",
  "password": "0",
  "country": "AZE",
  "createdOn": "2018-10-21T22:19:33.377Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

***route.js***

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: user._id }, { $push: { "notification.notidata": { "data.para": "Your Ad " + "'" + thisad.heading + "'" + " has been successfully submitted."} } }, { new: true }, function (err, df) { ....
```

I want `notidata` to be sorted by `notidate`. Using `$postion: 0` did not work. Nor did `$sort: notidate: -1`

*** failed $position attempt***

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: user._id }, { $push: { "notification.notidata": { "data.para": "Your Ad " + "'" + thisad.heading + "'" + " has been successfully submitted.", "$position": 0} } }, { new: true }, function (err, df) {....
```

***failed $sort attempt***

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: user._id }, { $push: { "notification.notidata": { "data.para": "Your Ad " + "'" + thisad.heading + "'" + " has been successfully submitted.", "$sort": {"notification.notidata.notidate": -1}} } }, { new: true }, function (err, df) {....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#up._S_sort) with `$each` operator and then you just specify the name of nested field (not entire path like in your example), try:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: user._id }, { 
    $push: {
        "notification.notidata": {
            "$each": [ { data: { para: "Your Ad " + "'" + thisad.heading + "'" + " has been successfully submitted." } } ],
            "$sort": {"notidate": -1}
        }
    }
}, {new: true})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. However, I wish to understand since every time this `User.findOneAndUpdate` will get executed in my app, it will have 1 entry of `notidata.para` to insert. Then why something like `$each`needs to be put in `$push`? Isn't `$each` for inserting more than one data (like an array of data)?

Comment: I know it might be confusing, it's even mentioned in the documentation that you should pass empty array if you only want to sort elements. That's by design

Comment: **Thanks a lot!**